# Storing Spaces and Colons in Cookie JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am making a webpage with a form that saves the data you type in cookies in case you accidentally close the tab or navigate away before submitting.

I would like to know if there is a way to allow whitespace and colons to be in my cookie's data? For instance if user types "test test", on refresh the cookie will be stored and displayed as "test%2520test". Similarly colons display as "%3A". I believe this is possible with using `encodeURIComponent` but I am not sure exactly how. Below I will include my `saveVideo, setCookie, and readCookie` JS functions as well as an example input field.

Also, **bonus question**: What would be the best way to delete each cookie's data upon submit of the form?

```
<input id="video" name="video" type="text" onchange="saveVideo(this.value);"/>
```

---

```
function saveVideo(cookieValue)
        {
            var sel = document.getElementById('video');

            saveclass = saveclass ? saveclass : document.body.className;
            document.body.className = saveclass + ' ' + sel.value;

            setCookie('video', cookieValue, 1   );
        }   


function setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, nDays) {
            var today = new Date();
            var expire = new Date();

            if (nDays==null || nDays==0)
                nDays=1;

            expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
            document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue) + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
        }


function readCookie(name) {
          var nameEQ = name + "=";
          var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
          for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
          }
          return null;
        }

        </script>
```

Any tips, pointers, general help is much appreciated!

Comment: You've already found the `encodeURIComponent` function. Now check out it's inverse: [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

Comment: check out the Storage API in modern Browsers. Like the [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your code to following in the `readCookie` function, using [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent):

```
return decodeURIComponent(c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length));
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't think it would be this easy, thanks! While I have you, what would be the most efficient way to delete multiple cookies on form submit?

Comment: Do you need a delete cookie function? Or do you need a multiple delete function?

Comment: Ideally a multiple function, where I can easily delete a list of seperate cookies. Thanks.

Comment: Deleting a cookie is easy, just ask for an array of cookie names and loop on it to do something like this: 
`document.cookie = name + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';`

Comment: Thanks for all the help!